# Issue with exporting Curve (Geometry node) Hair to Unreal Engine

Tags: geometry-nodes, export, hair, unreal-engine

I am trying to use the new Blender 3.5 Curve hair to create Groom for my character in Unreal Engine 5.2.

I successfully export the hair using Send to Unreal addon, but, I don't understand the relationship between the curve segment in Blender and UE5.

I made two hair curves to test out, here is the blender version, as you can see in the screenshot below, I made curveA 4 points, curveB 32 points, but they all display 7 segments in viewport, I know I can make them smooth but increase the additional subdivision in render setting, but it is not the point here, I am trying to understand the how the point count affect the segments, because it might affect the segment in unreal, please see next screenshot, you will see what I am talking about.
[image]

Here is the screenshot in UE5 after I import two curves, you can see they both have 8 segments.
[image]

It looks like the point count in Blender doesn't affect the segment at all, all curves have consistent 8 segments, it is not OK, I don't want my long hair to have the same segment with the Eyebrow, it is not enough for long hair, and too many for eyebrow.

Does anyone know how to control the segment? Ideally, it would make sense the point count in Blender controls the segment in UE. If anyone knows that would be much appreciated

Comment: That addon is a third-party addon and not supplied with native Blender so questions about it are off-topic here. Suggest you ask the addon authors. There seems to be a section about it in the addon documentation [here](https://epicgames.github.io/BlenderTools/send2ue/asset-types/groom.html#groom).

Comment: Do you know how to export a curve hair to UE without addon?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid. I know nothing about UE.